# Is it possible to specify more than one kerberos credential cache dedicated to each connection profile in sqlDeveloper?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, kerberos

Got SqlDeveloper to work with kerberos using thin drivers by generating credential cache file upfront using `kinit` and specifying the absolute file+path of `krb5.conf` and the same of credential cache file in the `Preference->Database->Advance->Kerberos Thin Config`

That works for one of my connection for `dev` database but the other connection is for `test` database and that is a different database.

Is there a way to somehow specify the different credential cache for different connection profiles in Sql Developer ?

Or no there way than to keep switching the credential cache/krb5.conf everytime you switch the connection ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: i have both macos and windows but its the same story